# Setting non-standard ImageResolution for EMF export as default

Tags: export, options, customization, undocumented, windows

Mathematica has a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7396898/758485) in that `BarChart`s and `ListPlot`s with `Filling` will export as a pixelated bitmap, not a vector graphic when exporting as EMF format.

There is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7561608/758485), which is to set `ImageResolution` to be 1300 or higher in the `Export` command, like this:

```
testdata = RandomReal[{5, 10}, 20];
bg1 = BarChart[{testdata}]
Export["bg1400.emf", bg1, ImageResolution -> 1400]
```

(No, you don't get a huge file if you set `ImageResolution` this high. It somehow tricks it into using vector graphics. However the workaround is a bit unreliable, depending on the graph in question.)

How can I make this option the default? `SetOptions[Export]={ImageResolution -> 1400}` produces an error message that it's not a recognised option to `Export`.  I also tried:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, ConversionOptions -> {"ExportOptions" -> {"EMF" -> 
  {"IncludeSpecialFonts" -> True, ImageResolution -> 1400}}}]
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

How do I set these export options as the default, e.g. in a package? Alternatively, how do I force this hidden vector capability?

Comment: Yet another bug that remains unfixed in new versions.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15272/pass-options-to-export?rq=1

Comment: Why don't you just Export to SVG and then use Inkscape (seems to be possible to use the command line) to convert to EMF? I tried it, seems to work fine. Don't ever wait for WRI to fix Export/Import issues. It seems to be much more important to do new stuff than to fix old stuff (which is understandable of course).

Comment: @RolfMertig because it won't be me doing it. It will be end users expecting the process to be at least as straightforward as the process they are currently using. If I can't deliver that, user acceptance could be affected.

Comment: I've got this same problem and see your related post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396898/why-do-barchart-graphics-exported-from-mathematica-have-pixelated-text-is-there. I've been chasing this like a dog after a bone and thought I'd share my research. @RolfMertig I took your advice without luck. Here is the image exported as a SVG http://imgur.com/GSyROEL and here it is http://imgur.com/awdU54t after the Inkscape command to convert it `"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" "C:\Temp\aGraph.svg" --export-emf=svgToEMFFormat.emf`.  - any other peoples suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: So an external conversion (e.g. PDF->EMF using [pstoedit](http://www.pstoedit.net/pstoedit) ) is out of the question, then?

Comment: @YvesKlett - it depends (1) if the fonts come through correctly and (2) if pstoedit can be piped to a .Net application (we are using a .Net frontend for this Mathematica application).