# The mysterious gap inside Grid

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts, spacing

There's this gap inside Grid which I cannot seem to remove. Perhaps someone knows how.

```
blocks = Table[{Graphics[{Darker@Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1000, 200}]}]}, {i, 6}]
myGrid = Grid[blocks, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: At 100% resolution.]

All nice and even at 100% zoom. Now if I zoom in on this to say 640% inside the notebook:
[image: At 640% resolution]

Extra space appears below each item as shown. The orange box received by clicking on the graphics suggests that Grid is responsible for the gap but Spacings have already been set to 0. Ssing Magnify will also cause the issue to appear at lower zoom rates. Does anyone know a fix for this in Grid? Or do I have to resort to GraphicsGrid which doesn't have this issue.

EDIT: This is the result produced from using the code as provided by Mike's answer (copy and pasted). 
[image: Mike]
And this one with it magnified so the code can be included in the screenshot.
[image: magnified]

I'm going to re-emphasize that this issue only occurs when I zoom in far enough or use Magnify.

Edit2: I'm on Mathematica 9.0.0

Comment: Add `PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0` to your `Graphics` code

Comment: That doesn't seem to cut it. I still get the white space after I zoom in (though it does make the problem more obvious)

Comment: please post a pic and the exact code that you used.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Version 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8). But I suspect it might have something to do with the default setting of `GridFrameMargins`. [`The default setting is GridFrameMargins->{{0.4,0.4},{0.5,0.5}}](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GridFrameMargins.html).

Comment: Sadly, no sugar with GridFrameMargins as well.

Comment: Kind of an issue if you are using the `Magnify` variant of the [EMF bar chart export hack](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31255/8)... Oh wait...

Comment: It seems this issue has gone at least from 12.1 Windows version.

Answer (score 13):

I can reproduce the problem described by OP in Mathematica 9.0.1 on Windows 8.1.

By using `` FrontEnd`UndocumentedBoxInformationPacket `` to check the displayed Boxes' layout in the FrontEnd, I wildly guess that the cause of the problem might be hiding in the FrontEnd layout engine (of only the Windows version maybe?). If it's true, then there might be nothing we users can do with it...

Here is my experiment and observation. I extracted the layout information and redrew them in a more clarified way (click image to see it larger; the code is attached afterward). In the screenshot, the upper green grid and the left column in this panel are corresponding to `Grid`, and the lower grid and the right column are to `GraphicsGrid`:

[image: demonstration of a possible bug from Grid or FrontEnd layout engine]

```
blocks = Table[{Graphics[{Darker@Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1000, 200}]}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> True, ImagePadding -> 0]}, {i, 2}];

myGrid      = Grid[blocks, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> All];
myGraphGrid = GraphicsGrid[blocks, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0];

gridNB      = myGrid // ToBoxes // Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[#], CellMargins -> 0, CellFrameMargins -> 0]}, ShowCellBracket -> False, Saveable -> False, WindowClickSelect -> False, Selectable -> False, WindowFrame -> "ThinFrame", WindowElements -> {}, WindowFrameElements -> {}, WindowMargins -> {{10, Automatic}, {Automatic, 10}}, WindowSize -> {200, 300}] & // NotebookPut;
graphGridNB = myGraphGrid // ToBoxes // Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[#], CellMargins -> 0, CellFrameMargins -> 0]}, ShowCellBracket -> False, Saveable -> False, WindowClickSelect -> False, Selectable -> False, WindowFrame -> "ThinFrame", WindowElements -> {}, WindowFrameElements -> {}, WindowMargins -> {{10, Automatic}, {Automatic, 320}}, WindowSize -> {200, 300}] & // NotebookPut;

{mgnf1, mgnf2} = 100 CurrentValue[#, Magnification] & /@ {gridNB, graphGridNB};
mgnfController1 = Row[{HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[mgnf1, (SetOptions[gridNB, Magnification :> #/100.]; mgnf1 = #) &], {10, 1000}], Style[Row[{Dynamic[mgnf1], "%"}], 20]}];
mgnfController2 = Row[{HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[mgnf2, (SetOptions[graphGridNB, Magnification :> #/100.]; mgnf2 = #) &], {10, 1000}], Style[Row[{Dynamic[mgnf2], "%"}], 20]}];

Clear[BRtoPolygon]
BRtoPolygon[boundingRect_, zCoord_: RandomReal[]] := Outer[List, ##] & @@ MapAt[Minus, boundingRect\[Transpose], 2] // MapAt[Reverse, #, 2] & // ArrayPad[Flatten[#, 1], {0, {0, 1}}, zCoord] & // Polygon

gridLayout = DynamicModule[{bips, layer, zCoordRule, hueRule},
            Dynamic[
                Module[{Graphics3DTemp, zCoord, hue},
                    bips = MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`UndocumentedBoxInformationPacket[#]] &[gridNB];
                    layer = bips //. {FE`BoxType -> bt_, FE`Position -> pos_, FE`BoundingRectangle -> br_, __, FE`Children -> chd_} :>
                                        {
                                            bt,
                                            If[And @@ (NumericQ /@ Flatten[{pos, br}]), 
                                                Function[{pts, zCoord}, 
                                                        Graphics3DTemp[{
                                                                        FaceForm[Hue[hue, .1, 1]], EdgeForm[Hue[hue, 1, .7]], BRtoPolygon[pts, zCoord], 
                                                                        If[MemberQ[{"GridBox", "GraphicsBox", "RectangleBox"},bt],
                                                                           Text[Style[bt, 15], Append[{1, -1} Last[pts], zCoord]], {}]
                                                                       }]
                                                        ][pos + # & /@ br, zCoord],
                                                Hold[Sequence[]]],
                                            chd
                                        } /. {bt_String, Hold[Sequence[]], chd_} :> Hold[Sequence[]] // ReleaseHold;
                    zCoordRule = Map[Function[{pos}, pos -> (layer[[##]] & @@ pos /. zCoord -> Length[pos])], Position[layer, Graphics3DTemp[__]]];
                    hueRule = Thread[# -> Rescale[Range[Length@#]]] &@Position[layer, hue];
                    ReplacePart[ReplacePart[layer, zCoordRule], hueRule] /. Graphics3DTemp -> Graphics3D // Cases[#, g_Graphics3D :> g, ∞] & // Rest //
                        Show[#,
                                Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Blue, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 17, Italic, Blue, Bold] & /@ {"width", "height", "layer"}),
                                Boxed -> False, ViewVertical -> {-1, 0, 0}, ViewPoint -> 1000 {-.9, -1, .5}, 
                                BoxRatios -> {Automatic, Automatic, 400}, ImageSize -> 700, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}] &
                    ],
                UpdateInterval -> 0]
            ];

graphGridLayout = DynamicModule[{bips, layer, zCoordRule, hueRule},
            Dynamic[
                Module[{Graphics3DTemp, zCoord, hue},
                    bips = MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`UndocumentedBoxInformationPacket[#]] &[graphGridNB];
                    layer = bips /. e : {FE`BoxType -> "InsetBox", FE`Position -> pos_, __, FE`Children -> {{FE`BoxType -> "GraphicsBox", __}}} :> ReplacePart[e, {6, 2, 1, 2, 2} -> pos] //.
                                    {FE`BoxType -> bt_, FE`Position -> pos_, FE`BoundingRectangle -> br_, __, FE`Children -> chd_} :>
                                        {
                                            bt,
                                            If[And @@ (NumericQ /@ Flatten[{pos, br}]), 
                                                Function[{pts, zCoord}, 
                                                        Graphics3DTemp[{
                                                                        FaceForm[Hue[hue, .2, 1]], EdgeForm[Hue[hue, 1, .7]], BRtoPolygon[pts, zCoord], 
                                                                        If[MemberQ[{"InsetBox", "GraphicsBox", "RectangleBox"}, bt],
                                                                           Text[Style[bt, 15], Append[{1, -1} First[pts], zCoord]], {}]
                                                                       }]
                                                        ][pos + # & /@ br, zCoord],
                                                Hold[Sequence[]]],
                                            chd
                                            } /. {bt_String, Hold[Sequence[]], chd_} :> Hold[Sequence[]] // ReleaseHold;
                    zCoordRule = Map[Function[{pos}, pos -> (layer[[##]] & @@ pos /. zCoord -> Length[pos] + Mean[pos[[1 ;; -1]]])], Position[layer, Graphics3DTemp[__]]];
                    hueRule = Thread[# -> Rescale[Range[Length@#]]] &@Position[layer, hue];
                    ReplacePart[ReplacePart[layer, zCoordRule], hueRule] /. Graphics3DTemp -> Graphics3D // Cases[#, g_Graphics3D :> g, ∞] & // Rest //
                        Show[#,
                                Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Blue, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 17, Italic, Blue, Bold] & /@ {"width", "height", "layer"}),
                                Boxed -> False, ViewVertical -> {-1, 0, 0}, ViewPoint -> 1000 {-.9, -1, .5}, 
                                BoxRatios -> {Automatic, Automatic, 700}, ImageSize -> 700, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}] &
                    ],
                UpdateInterval -> 0]
            ];

panel = Grid[{{mgnfController1, mgnfController2},
              {gridLayout, graphGridLayout}},
             Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Left, Top}] // ToBoxes //
          Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[#], "Output", CellMargins -> 0, CellFrameMargins -> 0]}, ShowCellBracket -> False, Saveable -> False, WindowElements -> {}, WindowFrame -> "ThinFrame", WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox"}, WindowMargins -> {{220, Automatic}, {Automatic, 10}}, WindowSize -> All] & // NotebookPut;
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to reproduce the effect (in version 7 under Windows) but I don't yet fully understand it.  Partly it appears when you have automatically-resizing `Graphics` objects contained in a `Grid` object that is wider than the Notebook window.  For example, using this code:

```
blocks = Table[{Graphics[{Darker@Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1000, 200}]}, 
     ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0]}, {i, 6}];

myGrid = Grid[blocks, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> All];

Style[myGrid, Magnification -> 3]
```

And in a Notebook window that is easily able to contain the Graphic I get a solid green area with only fine black dividers:

[image]

However, if I resize the Notebook window to a narrower-than-graphic size I see this:

[image]

However magnification also plays a role here.  Using a fixed `ImageSize`, which prevents resizing, combined with magnification shows a gap even when the Notebook is plenty wide to contain it:

```
Style[
 myGrid /. g_Graphics :> Show[g, ImageSize -> 50],
 Magnification -> 4
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Magnify 10 times or more, ...

The basic idea is to use a GraphicsGrid

```
blocks = Table[{Graphics[{Darker@Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 20}]},
  ImagePadding -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None]}, {i, 6}]

myGrid = GraphicsGrid[blocks, Spacings -> Scaled@.0, Frame -> All]
```

The options differ slightly for GraphicsGrid, see DocumentationCenter

Edit1: More workarounds...
Another approach is to "Rasterize" Graphics output or to "Pane" it

```
    blocks = Table[{Graphics[{Darker@Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, .2}]}, 
         ImagePadding -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None]}, {i, 6}] // 
      Map[Rasterize, #, {2}] &
    myGrid = Grid[blocks, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> All, 
      FrameStyle -> {Blue, AbsoluteThickness@3}]

    blocks = Table[{Graphics[{Darker@Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, .2}]}, 
         ImagePadding -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None]}, {i, 6}] // 
      Map[Pane, #, {2}] &
    myGrid = Grid[blocks, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> All, 
      FrameStyle -> {Blue, AbsoluteThickness@3}]
```

In simple cases setting grid's "Background" to Darker@Green is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Thanks hieron, did mention this in my original post that GraphicsGrid does work and is indeed a workaround for the given example. Though I would much prefer having a grid due to the flexibility in size it provides.

Answer (score 2):

```
blocks = Table[{Graphics[{Darker@Green, 
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1000, 200}]}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
    ImagePadding -> 0]}, {i, 6}]
myGrid = Grid[blocks, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

If you are still seeing whitespace as per your comment then please post a pic and the exact code that you used.

**Edit**

As per reply to Mr Wizard. At the max (max of widow element) magnification of 300% I get

[image]

Using Magnify of 6 (600%) I still do not see a problem:

[image]

I'm on OS X 10.9.4 and Mma 9.0.1

Comment: Note that the OP says: *All nice and even at 100% zoom. Now if I zoom in on this to say 640% inside the notebook:* so you must zoom to (theoretically) see the problem.  I *do* see the problem using version 7.

Comment: Okay, despite the OP's statement I don't think that is a factor.  I'm starting on an answer now.  Correcting myself a second time it seems magnification is a factor after all.  Gah.  I'm too tired!

Comment: I tried it at 300% before posting the answer.

Comment: please try the examples in my answer; it may not affect your system.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard as per above when applying `Magnify` (which is same as `Style[...,Magnification->..]`, which OP says is a problem, I see no problem. No more time to spend on this since for me it is a non issue. A late for lunch

Comment: Maybe it has been fixed in 9.0.1? So far the two 9.0.1 users have reported this as a non-issue.

Comment: @Jonie That may well be.  Also, I think I've seen this problem before, perhaps even as a Question here.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Could you please do me a favour and verify that zooming in to 300% on the Magnified 6 version still works? I can do Magnify 6 on mine too at 100% zoom, but not at 150%. Meanwhile I'll try get access to 9.0.1 and browse through the grid related questions here.

Comment: @Jonie have only just returned to this site. apologies for the delay. It appears to be a notebook resize issue. Having said that an answer below by hieron solves it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I did my investigations with V9.0.1 running on OS X. My findings may be (probably are) platform dependent.

First I eliminated the framing from the problem space by writing this code.

```
blocks =
  With[{size = {5, 1}},
    Table[
      Graphics[{
        {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Transparent], Rectangle[{0, 0}, size]},
        {Darker@Green, 
           Scale[Rectangle[{0, 0}, size], .95 {1., 1. - size[[2]]/size[[1]]}]}},
        PlotRangePadding -> None],
      {2}]];
```

This gives good results over a wide range of magnifications.

```
Magnify[Column[blocks, Spacings -> -.14], 1/2]
```

[image: blocks-0.5]

```
Magnify[Column[blocks, Spacings -> -.14], 3]
```

[image: blocks-3]

I actually got good results with magnifications up to 5.

However, when I tried a magnification of 6.4, I ran into the same problem that the question demonstrates. I could find no setting for `Spacings` that removed the gap between the blocks. Instead, the rendering engine start to eat up the lower block and I made the spacing more negative. The window capture below shows this.

[image: window-1]

`Magnify` isn't the only source of trouble. Look what happen when I shrink the notebook window.

[image: window-2]